# Getting a syntax error while reading user input of a string, python

Tags: python, if-statement

I'm having trouble getting my program to ask for user input once the initial for loop is completed. I think I may have to use continue or break, but I'm uncertain of how to do this in this situatuation. Thank you in advance for any help!
Specifically I'm getting a syntax error on my else statement when attempting to add any line that will ask again for the user to enter the number of rolls they desire.

```
'''
program that calculates the number of times
the sum of two randomly rolled dice equals each
each possible value given a read number of rolls.

outputs a histogram of rolls

program repeats until user enters a
negative number of rolls.
'''

import random

num_twos = 0
num_threes = 0
num_fours = 0
num_fives = 0
num_sixs = 0
num_sevens = 0
num_eights = 0
num_nines = 0
num_tens = 0
num_elevens = 0
num_twelves = 0
num_rolls = int(input('Enter number of rolls:\n'))
histogram_char = input('Choose a symbol to represent data:\n')


if num_rolls >= 1:
    for i in range(num_rolls):
        die1 = random.randint(1,6)
        die2 = random.randint(1,6)
        roll_total = die1 + die2

        #count number of each possible roll
        if roll_total == 2:
            num_twos += 1
        if roll_total == 3:
            num_threes += 1
        if roll_total == 4:
            num_fours += 1
        if roll_total == 5:
            num_fives += 1
        if roll_total == 6:
            num_sixs += 1
        if roll_total == 7:
            num_sevens += 1
        if roll_total == 8:
            num_eights += 1
        if roll_total == 9:
            num_nines += 1
        if roll_total == 10:
            num_tens += 1
        if roll_total == 11:
            num_elevens += 1
        if roll_total == 12:
            num_twelves += 1
    print('2s:  {}'.format(num_twos*histogram_char))
    #FIXME: continue histogram for numbers 3 through 12

    num_rolls = int(input('Enter number of rolls:\n')

else:
    print('{} is an invalid number of rolls, try again.')
```

Comment: You have unbalanced parentheses.  Just add the missing `)`.

Comment: Voting to close since it's just a typo.

Comment: I will close if the typo is the only error. But will my program run correctly elsewise? will it loop once the histogram is displayed and ask again for user input?

Comment: Fixed the parentheses and am still getting an error with the else statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgot to close parantheses

`num_rolls = int(input('Enter number of rolls:\n'))`

But `num_rolls` before `else` clause should be removed as it is not affecting the programm at all.

```
'''
program that calculates the number of times
the sum of two randomly rolled dice equals each
each possible value given a read number of rolls.

outputs a histogram of rolls

program repeats until user enters a
negative number of rolls.
'''

import random

num_twos = 0
num_threes = 0
num_fours = 0
num_fives = 0
num_sixs = 0
num_sevens = 0
num_eights = 0
num_nines = 0
num_tens = 0
num_elevens = 0
num_twelves = 0
num_rolls = int(input('Enter number of rolls:\n'))
histogram_char = input('Choose a symbol to represent data:\n')


if num_rolls >= 1:
  for i in range(num_rolls):
      die1 = random.randint(1,6)
      die2 = random.randint(1,6)
      roll_total = die1 + die2

      #count number of each possible roll
      if roll_total == 2:
        num_twos += 1
      if roll_total == 3:
        num_threes += 1
      if roll_total == 4:
        num_fours += 1
      if roll_total == 5:
        num_fives += 1
      if roll_total == 6:
        num_sixs += 1
      if roll_total == 7:
        num_sevens += 1
      if roll_total == 8:
        num_eights += 1
      if roll_total == 9:
        num_nines += 1
      if roll_total == 10:
        num_tens += 1
      if roll_total == 11:
        num_elevens += 1
      if roll_total == 12:
        num_twelves += 1
  print('2s:  {}'.format(num_twos*histogram_char))
  # num_rolls = int(input('Enter number of rolls:\n'))

else:
    print('{} is an invalid number of rolls, try again.')
```

**EDIT:**

```
while num_rolls >= 1:
  for i in range(num_rolls):
    die1 = random.randint(1,6)
    die2 = random.randint(1,6)
    roll_total = die1 + die2

    #count number of each possible roll
    if roll_total == 2:
      num_twos += 1
    if roll_total == 3:
      num_threes += 1
    if roll_total == 4:
      num_fours += 1
    if roll_total == 5:
      num_fives += 1
    if roll_total == 6:
      num_sixs += 1
    if roll_total == 7:
      num_sevens += 1
    if roll_total == 8:
      num_eights += 1
    if roll_total == 9:
      num_nines += 1
    if roll_total == 10:
      num_tens += 1
    if roll_total == 11:
      num_elevens += 1
    if roll_total == 12:
      num_twelves += 1
  print('2s:  {}'.format(num_twos*histogram_char))
  num_rolls = int(input('Enter number of rolls:\n'))

else:
  print('{} is an invalid number of rolls, try again.')
```

Comment: Still getting an error with my else statement

Comment: I had added the num_rolls read statement before the else statement so that the loop would continue with new user input. If this is not the way to do this can someone please enlighten me as to the correct way to repeat a loop with new user input.    Thank you everyone for helping a novice.

Comment: @Drkdeibs as requested in the EDIT section I put alternative for if-else with while-else

Comment: Thank you. So, if I'm understanding correctly a for loop will not work that way but a while loop can be used to reiterate a loop with new input? Thank you everyone, this helps to deepen my understanding of for loops and while loops!